# streamscraper java lib eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, libs

I have this code:

```
import java.net.URI;
import java.util.List;
import net.moraleboost.streamscraper.Stream;
import net.moraleboost.streamscraper.Scraper;
import net.moraleboost.streamscraper.scraper.IceCastScraper;

public class Harvester
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        Scraper scraper = new IceCastScraper();
        List<Stream> streams = scraper.scrape(new URI("http://host:port/"));
        for (Stream stream: streams) {
            System.out.println("Song Title: " + stream.getCurrentSong());
            System.out.println("URI: " + stream.getUri());
        }
    }
}
```

Where do I download JAR for import net.moraleboost.streamscraper.* to work? I can find source code for it but I gives me load of errors, can someone just provide me .jar so I could include in java build path library?

Comment: check out [here](https://code.google.com/p/streamscraper/source/browse/lib/httpmime-4.0-beta2.jar?r=42bb8de8b7a800d25d3deb951b11ecb83d6e3055) and [here](https://code.google.com/p/streamscraper/source/browse/src/net/moraleboost/streamscraper/scraper/ShoutCastScraper.java?r=42bb8de8b7a800d25d3deb951b11ecb83d6e3055)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can clone the repository at https://code.google.com/p/streamscraper/

You can also download the code from here: https://code.google.com/p/streamscraper/source/browse/